# TS + ES6 + Third Party Libraries

Tags: javascript, gulp, typescript, babel, ecmascript

Здравствуйте! Помогите побороть недуг.

Решил поэкспериментировать со связкой TS + Babel + ES6 modules. Для сборки использую gulp.

Вот код тестовой таски:

```
gulp.src(config.allTypeScript)
    .pipe(ts({
        removeComments: true,
        declarationFiles: false,
        target: "es6",
        module: "none"
    }))
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(concat("application.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./build"));
```

Хочу уточнить тот момент, что если при компиляции typescript указать *es5*, то он не видит фичи es6 (Map, Set, и т.д.). Однако, если ставить *es6*, то выводится такая ошибка:

> TypeScript error: typings/marionette/marionette.d.ts(1422,2): Error TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 6 or higher. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"' or 'import d from "mod"' instead.

```
declare module 'backbone.marionette' {
   import Backbone = require('backbone');

   export = Marionette;
}
```

С учётом того, что это сторонняя вещь, которую править бы не хотелось, можно ли узнать разумное решение всего этого?

Comment: Забыл сказать, что до этого проект был сделан на commonjs через browserify, потом прикрутил babelify, но чуда не случилось =(

Comment: @shatal TS не очень хорошо компилит. Но даже если убрать babel, я не очень понимаю, как мне решить проблемы модулей

Comment: @shatal проблема в том, что при компиляции вылетают ошибки. Пример кода сверху

Comment: @shatal вопрос я обновил и добавил текущую пробему

Comment: Я надеюсь что Вы смогли решить проблему, так как искренне сочувствую Вам. Но помочь не могу, потому что не знаю чем. Единственное на что я хочу обратить внимание, это упоминание в тексте ошибки, что стоит изменить импорт на предложенные вам варианты. Вы пробовали изменить содержание самого импорта?

Comment: а зачем вы third party вообще компилируете ? по идее npm вам их собрать в js уже должен.